# Failure in using DolphinDB MySQL plugin

Tags: dolphindb

I used to connect to MySQL database from DolphinDB. I started with the following code:

```
loadPlugin("plugins/mysql/PluginMySQL.txt")
conn =connect("localhost",3306,"root","12345","mydb")
```

It returned an error:

```
Syntax Error: [line #22] Cannot recognize the token connect
```

Then I tried to replace “connect” with “mysql::connect”, but it still reported an error:

```
ConnectionFailed : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) ((nullptr):0), with errno: 2002
```

Can someone help me figure this out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You shall use IP address instead of “localhost”. This plugin does not support socket link. You can only use TCP.
Hope this tip could help you!